# How to read single line from file in Erlang

Tags: string, file, erlang

I'm new to Erlang and stackoverflow. I've been searching the threads on how to read a string from a .txt file using Erlang. I'd also like to separate it into words using `string:tokens` I've been told I can use io:get_line to accomplish this but I must be doing something wrong. Here is the code I wrote. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
-module(lab6).
-export([file/1]).

file(fName) ->
file:open(fName, [read]),
string:tokens(io:get_line(fName), ". ").
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-module(lab6).
-export([file/1]).

file(FName) ->  % a variable must start by an Upper case character, otherwise it is an atom
    {ok,IoDevice} = file:open(FName, [read]), % file:open/2 returns the tuple {ok,IoDevice} if it succeeds.
                                              % IoDevice is the file descriptor you will use for further accesses
    string:tokens(io:get_line(IoDevice,""), ". "). % you must use the file descriptor to read a new line, get_line
                                               % is expecting 2 arguments, the second one is a prompt, not used here
                                               % this code will split the first line of the file FName using
                                               % the dot and the white space as separators. It will then returns
                                               % the results letting the file open, but with the file descriptor
                                               % lost! so no chance to continue to read the lines like this.
```

You could have a look to [Learn you some erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content), It is an excellent site to learn Erlang.

Comment: Thank you so much Pascal! I can't believe that I forgot the uppercase! That was the main source of my error this entire time. How frustrating!